# Display list from model in ASP.Net MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is my model:

```
public class ViewInvoice
{
    public string ClientLocation { get; set; }
    public List<DetailsGroup> Details { get; set; }

    public class DetailsGroup
    {
        public List<string> Product { get; set; }
        public List<string> ProductSize { get; set; }
        public List<string> PackageType { get; set; }
        public List<DateTime> OrderDate { get; set; }
        public List<DateTime> DeliveryDate { get; set; }
        public List<int> OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public List<decimal> Price { get; set; }
        public List<int> ItemQuantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am trying to display this model in a table within my razor view. Here is that code:

```
@using MyModel.MyTools.Orders.SumOrder
@model SumOrder

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View Invoice";
}

<h2>View Invoice</h2>

<table>
    @foreach(var prod in Model.OCI)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @prod.ClientLocation
            </td>
        </tr>
         foreach (var orderItem in prod.Details)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @orderItem.Product
                </td>
                <td>
                    @orderItem.ItemQuantity
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

The first row in the table displays correctly, which is the name of a city, but in the next row I get this:

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]     System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

Can someone explain to me why I can not get the list returned in a readable format, and how to correct this problem?

Here is the code I used to group the list for the ViewInvoice model:

```
// group the cartItems according to location
        List<ViewInvoice> ordersGrouped = cartItems.GroupBy(c => new 
            {c.ClientLocation})
            .OrderBy(c => c.Key.ClientLocation).Select(s =>
                new ViewInvoice()
                    {
                        ClientLocation = s.Key.ClientLocation,
                        Details = new List<ViewInvoice.DetailsGroup>()
                            {
                                new ViewInvoice.DetailsGroup()
                                    {
                                        Product = s.Select(p => p.Product).ToList(),
                                        ItemQuantity = s.Select(p => p.ItemQuantity).ToList(),
                                        DeliveryDate = s.Select(p => p.DeliveryDate).ToList(),
                                        OrderDate = s.Select(p => p.OrderDate).ToList(),
                                        OrderNumber = s.Select(p => p.OrderNumber).ToList(),
                                        PackageType = s.Select(p => p.PackageType).ToList(),
                                        Price = s.Select(p => p.Price).ToList(),
                                        ProductSize = s.Select(p => p.ProductSize).ToList()
                                    }

                            }

                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: your question is not clear. Can you show us the controller? Given that Model.OCI is a list of ViewInvoice, this should work fine. Please show us the full error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I finally solved my problem. I initially over-thought the problem. I simplified my model, and added some simple logic to my view.

Here is the updated Model:

```
public class ViewInvoice
{
    public string ClientLocation { get; set; }
    public List<string> Product { get; set; }
    public List<string> ProductSize { get; set; }
    public List<string> PackageType { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> OrderDate { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public List<int> OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> Price { get; set; }
    public List<int> ItemQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

the updated code used to group the list for the Model:

```
// group the cartItems according to location
        List<ViewInvoice> ordersGrouped = cartItems.GroupBy(c => new 
            {c.ClientLocation})
            .OrderBy(c => c.Key.ClientLocation).Select(s =>
                new ViewInvoice()
                    {
                        ClientLocation = s.Key.ClientLocation,
                        Product = s.Select(p => p.Product).ToList(),
                        ItemQuantity = s.Select(p => p.ItemQuantity).ToList(),
                        DeliveryDate = s.Select(p => p.DeliveryDate).ToList(),
                        OrderDate = s.Select(p => p.OrderDate).ToList(),
                        OrderNumber = s.Select(p => p.OrderNumber).ToList(),
                        PackageType = s.Select(p => p.PackageType).ToList(),
                        Price = s.Select(p => p.Price).ToList(),
                        ProductSize = s.Select(p => p.ProductSize).ToList()

                    }).ToList();
```

and the updated view:

```
@using MyModel.MyTools.Orders.SumOrder
@model SumOrder

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View Invoice";
}

<h2>View Invoice</h2>
@{
    int i = 0;
}
<table>
    @foreach(var mod in Model.OCI)
    {
        var modCount = @mod.Product.Count();
        <tr>
            <th>@mod.ClientLocation</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        foreach (var items in mod.Product)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @mod.Product.ElementAtOrDefault(i)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @mod.Price.ElementAtOrDefault(i)
                </td>
            </tr>
            i++;
        }

    }
</table>
```

This solution clearly allows me to iterate through the model reproducing any required rows or cells along the way.  Played Russian roulette for the past two days over this problem. Hope this saves some time for others facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your model object doesn't make any sense. Why is each of your properties such as Price and Quantity a collection? A single order line item object will have just a single value for each of the properties, not a collection. Your invoice object already accounts for multiple Details object, but a single detail object should not have it's properties as lists. Remove the List<> from all your properties and it should solve it.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make any sense to me either, lol. I am trying to figure out how to correctly represent a list that I grouped using linq. I'll add the linq code above.

Comment: You still didn't explain why your Details object has each of it's properties as a collection instead of a singular value. To me it seems they should not be lists

Comment: Well, I did try it that way initially, but I didn't seem to have access to the properties in my view.  In example, I could no longer write **var orderItem in prod.Details**  This is my first attempt at trying to display a grouped list in a view, so I am sure that I am just missing some simple logic in my code. I just don't know what it is.

Comment: Leave public List<DetailsGroup> Details { get; set; } line as is, but every other list you don't need. After this instead of this: 

Product = s.Select(p => p.Product).ToList()

You should be able to do this:

Product = s.Product

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. I can't write: Product = s.Product. However, I can write either: Product = s.FirstOrDefault().Product or s.Select(p => p.Product).FirstOrDefault(), but this only will render the first element of the sequence.  That's the issue I can't seem to get around.

Answer (score 0):

Because a List of strings is not the same as a string. 
What you are seeing is what the ToString() method of the List class is returning, the default value.

**To get the elements from the list in a comma separated display use:**

```
string.Join(",", orderItem.Product.ToArray())
string.Join(",", orderItem.ItemQuantity.ToArray())
```

Whenever you want to print something that object's ToString() method will be called. 
This ToString() method defined on the List<> class cannot know how you would like your data to be displayed, seeing how a list can caontain more than one String or int or Date. You may want to add a <p> in front of every value and a </p> after every value for example.

The first row is showing up correctly because ClientLocation is a simple type.
For some more info on simple types see [simple types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691144%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)